# Best Approach to create map related content types in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to display a number of maps (for police stations, fire stations, health facilities, etc....) on my site. Each map attribute is different from the other. Example: the fire stations will include the number of fire fighters while the health facility will include the number of beds. Should I create a different content type for each?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use to create node for content which will have its own page. If you have a page for each fire station, yes you can create a node type. For content which will not have its own page, you can use Entity API (http://drupal.org/node/1261744). It is much lighter !